# Create a selection sorting method with the help of a findMin method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've been tasked with creating a selection sorting method (sorts elements in ascending order) that is aided by a `findMin` method.

My issue here is that I'm not sure where I'm supposed to call the `findMin` method within the selection sorting method. Also, I'm dubious about whether I did my `findMin` method correctly based off the requirements that are in the comments.

```
public class idk{

    // find the minimun valued element
    // range [start, ar.length - 1]
    //   int indexOfMin= -1; this is incorrect!!!

    // return indexOfMin; 
    public static int findMin(int [] ar, int start)
    {
        int minValue = ar[0];
        for (int i = start; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] < minValue) 
                minValue = ar[i];

        }

        return minValue;
    }
    public static void swap(int[] list, int a , int b){

        int temp = list[a];
        list[a] = list[b];
        list[b] = temp;
    }
    // 1) make a new array, copy the values from arr
    // into it and THEN sort res
    // 2) implement and use in this method 
    // the findMin helper method defined above

    public static int [] selSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int [] res= new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            res[i] = arr[i];

        int min = res.length;
        for (int x =0; x < res.length; x++){
            min = x;
            for (int y = x + 1; y < res.length;y++){
                if (res[y] < res[min])
                    min = y;
            }

            swap (res,x, min);        
        }
        return res;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

1. Convert your array into min-heap.
2. Now, top-most element of min-heap is the smallest element of the array.
3. get this element by calling your findMin() method and swap this element with the last element of an array then decrease the size of min heap.
4. Heapify your min-heap.
5. repeat step 1 to 4 till heap size>1

with this approach, you will get array sorted in decreasing order, or reverse it for increasing order.